# DD-WRT Additional Cron Jobs aren't running

Tags: router, dd-wrt, cron

I have installed DD-WRT (v24-sp2 (06/23/14) std - build 24461) on a TP-Link TL-WR841ND v9 and I'm trying to add a CRON job to update my Unlocator IP configuration as described here: [How to set up a Cronjob on DD-WRT to Auto Update Your IP](https://support.unlocator.com/customer/portal/articles/1479791-how-to-set-up-a-cronjob-on-dd-wrt-to-auto-update-your-ip).  However the cron job doesn't ever seem to run (I tried changing the time and date fields to * * * * * to run every minute - still no luck).

In my DD-WRT log file I have a number of entries like this:

```
DD-WRT cron.info cron[2106]: (crontabs) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
```

A bit of Googling suggests this might be due to a mis configured user account for the CRON process, however I haven't found any clear instructions on how to fix the issue.  I was hoping that anything added to the *Additional Cron Jobs* field on the DD-WRT Management page would 'just work'.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks like the CRON job may have been running and the problem was that the job was calling wget on an https urls.  The BusyBox wget that comes with DD-WRT doesn't seem to support https and I think the command was silently failing.

The URL given by Unlocator redirects to `https://unlocator.com/tool/api.php?api_key=X`, however it's possible to access this URL directly with HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

CRON Service falling asleep in V24

The cron service is frequently falling asleep and cron jobs are not executed. This requires a stopservice cron; startservice cron or a reboot. V23 does not have this problem.